# javascript str.split(":") "Uncaught ReferenceError: myArray is not defined"

Tags: javascript, split

When the code below is run I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: myArray is not defined"

```
this.GetClass  = function(klass) {
  $.each(jsonArray, function(i,val){
    var classes = val.class;
    myArray = classes.split(":")    
  });
}
```

Please comment

Comment: No you don't. If `myArray` wasn't defined and you ran that code, it would create a property called `myArray` on the global object.

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Where do you define `myArray` ?

Comment: My bet is on you using `use strict` somewhere. This error will appear because you've not defined `myArray`.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume your file starts with `'use strict;'` - you are forcing javascript into strict mode.  In which case, you can either remove that line, or change

```
myArray = classes.split(":")
```

to

```
window.myArray = classes.split(":");
```

To force it into the global scope.  Or define it in the scope it is needed in, most likely outside that function so it is available wherever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using strict mode. Thus you have to say `var` or attach it to an object.

Put another way `myArray` is not defined.

http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/dR7za/

In non-strict mode, the variable would have been hoisted up to global space, something that one usually do not want.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you are most likely in strict mode and trying to assign to an undeclared variable.

Since there is no reason to create a global variable in that way (in a loop), I assume you just forgot to add `var`:

```
var myArray = ...;
```